# Can Kotlin declare variable in if statement?

Tags: kotlin

I have a piece of code:

```
class Test {
    fun test() {
        val fruit = if (Apple().doSomeThing() != null) {//1
            val result = Apple().doSomeThing()       //2
            //...use result
        } else if (Banana().doSomeThing() != null) {
            Banana().doSomeThing()
        } else {
            Peach().doSomeThing()
        }

    }

    internal open class Fruit

    internal class Apple : Fruit() {

        fun doSomeThing(): Boolean? {
            return false
        }
    }

    internal class Banana : Fruit() {
        fun doSomeThing(): Boolean? {
            return false
        }
    }

    internal class Peach : Fruit() {

        fun doSomeThing(): Boolean? {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

It call **Apple().doSomeThing()** twice, can i declare a variable in if statement like this:?

```
var result :Boolean? = null
if((result = Apple().doSomeThing()) != null){
     //result.xxxx  //use result directly
}
```

And,how can i write **test()** method more gracefully!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `let` function ([doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#let)) to avoid calling `Apple().doSomething()` twice and chain them with elvis operator `?:` as below

```
    val fruit = Apple().doSomeThing()?.let {
        if (it) { // use the value of Apple().doSomething() here
            
        } else {
            
        }
    } ?: Banana().doSomeThing()?.let {
        if (it) {
            
        } else {
            
        }
    } ?: Peach().doSomeThing()?.let {
        if (it) {
            
        } else {
            
        }
    }
```

`it` within the scope of `let` in `Apple().doSomeThing()?.let { }` would have the value of `Apple().doSomeThing()` when it is not equal to null. And if `Apple().doSomeThing()` is equal to null, the elvis operator `?:` would enable evaluating the next expression, that is `Banana().doSomeThing()?.let { }` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, but you can do so inside of when. The thing to note is that x is immutable.

```
when (val x = foo()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, a nicer version of `test()`:

```
fun test() {
    val foo = Apple().doSomeThing()?.let { result ->
        //... use result
    } ?: Banana().doSomeThing()?.let { result ->
        //...use result
    } ?: Peach().doSomeThing()
}
```

Second, if you don't need to check all of the fruits in order, you can make much better use of inheritance:

```
fun test() {
    val fruit = listOf(Apple(), Banana(), Peach()).random()
    val result = fruit.doSomeThing()
}

interface Fruit {
    fun doSomeThing(): Boolean?
}

class Apple : Fruit {
    override fun doSomeThing(): Boolean? = false
}

class Banana : Fruit {
    override fun doSomeThing(): Boolean? = false
}

class Peach : Fruit {
    override fun doSomeThing(): Boolean? = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to the other answers: in the case where you're not doing anything else with the return values, it can simplify down to:

```
fun test() {
    val fruit = Apple().doSomeThing()
             ?: Banana().doSomeThing()
             ?: Peach().doSomeThing()

}
```